# Change Internet Explorer Build

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I'm having a little problem on a webpage, but it occurs only on Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 8.1, build `11.0.9600.18053`.  My actual installed build is the latest, which is `11.0.9600.18098`

All other IE versions are working as expected, that problem occurs ONLY on that build.

Can I revert to another IE build?

Comment: Why do you want to revert to a broken build?

Comment: Because I need to solve a CSS problem on that page, that occurs only on that build. Sometime customers are really harassing

Comment: They still don't understand that updating IE it's smooth and simple, and it's quite annoying

Comment: I can imagine :/ The only thing I can think of is for you to uninstall the Windpws Update patches for IE one by one until your version changes.

Comment: I have been having problems lately too, which page are you having problems with?  Mine have all been pages that have videos embedded in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've found that downgrade IE build is quite impossible ( other than unuseful, at all )

You can downgrade IE version ( i.e. from 11 to 8,7 or something similar ) but I'll never suggest you to do that ( you can emulate previous IE versions on last one ) because when you will have found the Windows Update related to IE build, the problem you were trying to solve has never existed.

And that was what happened. :)